# VIM,Vundle, You Complete me

Tags: vim, c++, vim-plugin, vimrc

I'm trying to use you complete me in vim. Here are the steps I've taken

```
sudo apt-get install vim    
sudo apt-get install git    
sudo apt-get install clang-3.5    
sudo git clone "https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

I added this to /etc/vimrc and ~/.vimrc

```
set nocompatible  
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe' 
call vundle#end() 

filetype plugin indent on
```

issued this shell command

```
vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

Didn't get any errors during all the steps above, but when I do this

```
vim test.cpp
```

enter insert mode and start typing

```
\#include
```

I don't get any code completion. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You ran `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` with `sudo`.  This put it Vundle in `/root/`.  You need to follow the [instructions for Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md) and issue the command correctly:

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Comment: your answer is correct. I did this to fix my mistake 1) sudo mv ~/.vim ~/OLDvim 2) mkdir ~/.vim 3) mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle. Then I did the git without sudo.

Comment: Actually your answer does correct an installation mistake but I still didn't get code completion to work there are lots of steps I took to redo my install but I'll but that in my answer not this comment