# Vim plugin, You Complete Me. Why does :YcmRestartServer hang?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I finally got [you complete me installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876253/vim-vundle-you-complete-me/876313#876313).

The plugin installed sucessfully. But didn't get auto complete as I typed.I looked at the help and tried

```
:YcmRestartServer
```

It hangs for several hours.

I issued this command:

```
:YcmDiags
```

Here is the output

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=33628): Max retries exceeded with url:
/semantic_completion_available (Caused by  NewConnectionError('<requests.package
s.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7e3f6f2320>: Failed to establi
sh a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Which of the previous answers from your previous question helped you install it?

Comment: Well none of them. The steps I put in my previous question I put together from many different google searches.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue by going in to ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/ and running `python install.py`

Comment: I got the error Cmake is not able to find Python-libraries. I looked up the solution to this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174394/cmake-is-not-able-to-find-python-libraries

Comment: forget my last comment

Comment: CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Cold NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS). I set PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/include/python2.7. thats where mine is

Comment: and got the same error. Also this is my PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so

Comment: okay after doing sudo apt-get install python-dev, python install.py completed without errors. now I'll see if YCM works.

Comment: Now I get this error "Received invalid HMAC response !"

Comment: Well even though the YcmRestartServer got that error. I discovered the code completion was working. I also had to create a .ycm_extra_conf.py file for my project folder. I used the sample one that came with YCM